# How to filter date from meta property with ImportXML in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, metadata, google-sheets-formula

I'm setting up a Google Sheet to scrape the publish dates from certain articles on my site. [Here's an example post](https://www.heyitsfree.net/free-historic-mexican-recipe-cookbooks/) if it helps.

I have meta tags generated for every post that look like this:

```
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2018-12-14T19:41+00:00" />
```

Thus, I use this code to scrape the publish date, with Column A being the link location:

```
=IMPORTXML(A2,"//meta[@property='article:published_time']/@content")
```

However, that scrapes the full meta content, which includes the time: **2018-12-14T19:41+00:00**

I merely want the **2018-12-14** while stripping everything from T-onward. Is there a way to filter it out somehow with xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(A2, "//meta[@property='article:published_time']/@content"), "(.+)T")
```

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so very much!

I would have spent all night trialing and erroring my way through this, you saved me a huge headache.