# Solved: Extract date from my Substack webpage to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, metadata

longtime lurker, first-time poster. I usually solve my issues & upvote without needing to post, but I've been stumped all weekend!

Edit: Erik solved it:
I was looking for an answer to extract the "datePublished" or "dateModified" from a Substack article in a Google Sheet.

Goal: This will tell me when it was the last date/time I updated, for example, my [PS5 restock](https://www.theshortcut.com/p/ps5-restock) guide, my [Walmart PS5 restock](https://www.theshortcut.com/p/walmart-ps5-restock) guide, etc. If it's too stale, I try to add relevant information. Having it in Google Sheets makes it streamlined as there are dozens of guides.

Test Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hLBFMWCTc2hpC-1C8Sxd5OVREdNHTVTtrJsAAU5Jl94/edit#gid=0

I've done this before for other sites I've worked at, but there appears to be no date in the meta data on Substack :/ (I could be wrong, as I'm no expert at reading XPATH)

I do see this in the body for the linked example:

```
<time datetime="2022-07-29T11:52:00.000Z">Jul 29</time>
```

I've been trying things like this (where E17 is where I put the article URL in Google Sheets) to no effect.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(E17, "//time[@datetime='datePublished']/@content"), "(.+)T")
```

I've been mostly working off of [this StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63514991/how-to-filter-date-from-meta-property-with-importxml-in-google-sheets), but I haven't been able to apply the same finding to Substack's formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to grab it directly using a Google Sheets formula, this should work for you:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*",FLATTEN(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://www.theshortcut.com/p/ps5-restock","//div[2]"),"Swider(.?.?.?.?\d\d{1}[hrago\s]*)"))),1,FALSE),"???"))`

To set realistic expectations, I usually can't invest this much time into working out such a solution on this forum. But I'm on vacation at the moment and filling time while my guest is otherwise occupied.

One further note: this is *specific* to the two sites you gave as examples. It will only work for sites where the second `<div>` holds this information and only where the data exists as strings exactly like those found on these two sites (including the poster's last name as "Swider").

**ADDENDUM:**

Looking at this further, did you try simply the following?

`=IMPORTXML(C2, "//time")`

(assuming your URL is in C2, etc.)

This seems to work for me, given that it appears the date/time data you want is contained within the first `<time>` element on the web page.

Comment: Thanks, Erik I appreciate the effort – while you're on vacation, too!

I got it to work, but you're right – it's overly complicated and limited to the author (I'm not sure why it can't be simpler like other sites, but I'm guessing it's to do with how Substack is coded?

Here's my work-in-prorgess
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hLBFMWCTc2hpC-1C8Sxd5OVREdNHTVTtrJsAAU5Jl94/edit#gid=0

Comment: See my addendum to my post.

Comment: Thank you, Erik. I clearly don't quite understand how XPATH works in each case and why some strings are fairly complicated looking and this is just //time (in my eyes, it almost feels like it's picked at random [I know it's not]). But I appreciate the help! You pitching in makes this forum an incredibly helpful resource. Thank you 

Comment: Glad it worked as expected, Matt. Easy win.